Android Phone Won't Turn On
I just recently had an issue with my phone. It's a Samsung Galaxy A51 (not the 5G, SM-A515U) from Xfinity Mobile (Android 13). Unfortunately, the screen is cracked. It still was functioning properly until now. It has not been rooted. I earlier this year had the issue with the grey ring and lightning bolt, but I solved that with some help from Redditors. Nonetheless, the problem never went away; I was using the phone as I normally do and it suddenly froze, so I hooked it up to my computer and used the ADB to reboot. It won't turn back on. When I repeatedly tap the power button, the phone vibrates and an alarm sounds. When I hold the Power key to turn it on, the phone vibrates, but the screen is blank. I can see the phone in my Device Manager and the ADB on my computer, but it doesn't show up in Windows Explorer (Windows 11 23H2). I can't even boot into Recovery mode. I could really use some help, as I've no money to fix my phone and it's the only one I have.

Seems like the display is finally gone.

Nevermind, I fixed it!
